# Query MediaStore.Audio.Media using Android Architecture components?

Tags: android, mvvm, android-contentprovider, android-room

I have been looking at Android Architecture Components LiveData, Room and ViewModel (MVVM). It saves us the hassle of using loaders and monitoring our data on our database tables. But I'm trying to find out if we can use LiveData and this architecture to query Medistore.Audio.Media and other such Uri's provided via ContentProviders.

Comment: did you have found any solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Room works with SQLite, not other sources of data, such as a `ContentProvider`.

There should be nothing stopping you from creating a `ProviderLiveData` that uses a background thread, a `ContentResolver`, and even a `ContentObserver`, to retrieve and keep updated some data retrieved from a `ContentProvider`. Similarly, a `ViewModel` could hold a `Cursor`, or a `ProviderLiveData`.

Comment: The fact that AAC totally ignore all other legacy systems, like content providers, has been a major pain the backside for me. There is often no easy route to migration. You mention some kind of hybrid LiveData here, that should already be part of AAC.

Comment: Could you perhaps elaborate a bit more on this? How can we keep a cursor in live data if we are supposed to close it when we don't need it anymore?

Comment: @Chapz: When you get a fresh `Cursor` to deliver via the `LiveData`, close the old one, I guess. I have not needed to implement something like this, so I do not have all of the details.